# How do i configure Printer Accounting (input copy code) for Xerox printers in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, printer, printing

I am trying to follow [instructions](https://cs.stanford.edu/system/files/public/xerox-win_0.pdf) for setting up a printer with a copy code, but I cannot the "Configuration" tab in Win8, and cannot find the "Accounting" place where I can input a copy code.

What is the Windows 8 equivalent for these things?

Comment: Did you download the specific driver noted (PostScript driver for WorkCentre 7775)? Does the printer Properties show it as the right Xerox model?  Did you create the specified port exactly as shown?

Comment: Yes. Note that the instructions are intended for Windows versions up through Win7, and they have not published for Win8, which is why I am asking about the Win8 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the printer and rather than opening last item from the context menu(Properties), select "Printer Properties". That will show you the Configuration tab where you can click Accounting button.